# What's the restful way to implement a forgotten password feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have the following restful structure:

- My login page uses the session/new action
- My signup page the users/new action
- My logout page uses the session/destroy action
- My register process uses the users/create action

I need 3 more actions for:

- I forgot my password page
- Start forgotten password action (send email)
- Reset password based on token

Where do these 3 actions fit in a restful world?

To clarify:

I know I can create whatever actions on my existing session and user controllers (eg. a reset_password get action or a start_reset_password post action) it just doesn't really sit right, it seems I am trying to make these controllers do too much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new controller called forgotten_passwords, to control the process

- forgotten_passwords - new : maps to I forgot my password page
- forgotten_passwords - create : maps to start forgotten password action (send email with token)
- forgotten_passwords - show : maps to the end of the process (a page where the user sees her new password)

I am pretty happy with this design. I think it called for a new controller.

Comment: That's a little ridiculous. A forgotten password retrieval function is more suited to RPC, not REST. So don't worry so much about shoehorning it in.

Answer (score 2):

REST is not black magic.  Figure out what your technical goals are for these pages, then pick the right verbs to go with them.

I forgot my password page: essentially a static form, right?  You want this to be cachable.  GET on any URL you want.

Send email: costly action which you don't want repeated and you DO want executed every time the user requests it: POST or PUT on any URL you want.  Heck, you could make it the same as the above URL if you wanted to, but I don't see a particularly pressing need to.

Reset password based on token: I'd consider implementing this as a login-via-token instead, but if you're going to do it your way, then it has server-side consequences and hence should probably be a POST or PUT.

Comment: I guess there is a battle between, wack whatever verbs and actions on your controllers that you need in order to get stuff done and, keep your controllers simple and only have the magic 7 verbs.